# Programmatically find and navigate to record on subreport in MS Access using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, report

In Access, I can navigate to a record in a subform by using code similar to:

```
Dim rs As Recordset
Set rs = Me.Form.RecordsetClone
rs.FindFirst "CodeID = " & MyID
Me.Form.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
```

Is there any way to do something similar with subreports, or any other way to navigate to a record within a subreport without using filters to only show one record? I'm looking to still be able to see the other records in the report, having the focus jump to the relevant record.

Comment: Reports are not intended to be interactive and I don't think they even have a RecordsetClone property. `DoCmd.GoToRecord` does offer acDataReport parameter so I tested this. With report in ReportView, acNext parameter works but acGoTo will not. So I have to say No, there is not a way to do this with report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do it. Assuming the report is embedded as a subreport:

```
Me.rptTest.SetFocus
DoCmd.SearchForRecord , "", acFirst, "[IDField] = " & RelevantID
```